# Prometheus AlertManager - Send Alerts to different clients based on routes

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have 2 services **A** and **B** which I want to monitor. Also I have 2 different notification channels **X** and **Y** in the form of `receivers` in the AlertManager config file.

I want to send to notify **X** if service **A** goes down and want to notify **Y** if service **B** goes down. How can I achieve this my configuration?

My AlertManager YAML file is:

```
route:
  receiver: X

receivers:
  - name: X
    email_configs:

  - name: Y
    email_configs:
```

And `alert.rule` files is:

```
groups:

- name: A
  rules:
    - alert: A_down
      expr: expression
      for: 1m
      labels:
         severity: critical
      annotations:
         summary: "A is down"

- name: B
  rules:
    - alert: B_down
      expr: expression
      for: 1m
      labels:
        severity: warning
      annotations:
        summary: "B is down"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The config should roughly look like this (not tested):

```yaml
    route:
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 2h

      receiver: 'default-receiver'

      routes:
      - match:
          alertname: A_down
        receiver: X
      - match:
          alertname: B_down
        receiver: Y

The idea is, that each [`route`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#%3Croute%3E) field can has a `routes` field, where you can put a different config, that gets enabled if the labels in `match` match the condition.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. BTW, can we use label based alert filtering rather then `alertname`?

Comment: Yes, you can filter based on any label in the alert.

Comment: Which versions support this?

Answer (score 4):

For clarifying - The **General Flow** to handle alert in Prometheus (Alertmanager and Prometheus integration) is like this:

> SomeErrorHappenInYourConfiguredRule(**Rule**) -> RouteToDestination(**Route**)
> -> TriggeringAnEvent(**Reciever**)-> GetAMessageInSlack/PagerDuty/Mail/etc...

**For example:**

> *if my aws machine cluster production-a1 is down, I want to trigger an event sending "pagerDuty" and "Slack" to my team with the relevant error.*

There's 3 files important to configure alerts on your prometheus system:

1. alertmanager.yml - configuration of you **routes** (getting the triggered
   errors) and **receivers** (how to handle this errors)
2. rules.yml - This rules will contain all the thresholds and rules
   you'll define in your system.
3. prometheus.yml - global configuration to integrate your rules into routes and recivers together (the two above).

I'm attaching a Dummy example In order to demonstrate the idea, in this example I'll watch overload in my machine (using node exporter installed on it):
On /var/data/prometheus-stack/alertmanager/**alertmanager.yml**

```yaml
    global:
      # The smarthost and SMTP sender used for mail notifications.
      smtp_smarthost: 'localhost:25'
      smtp_from: 'JohnDoe@gmail.com'
    
    route:
      receiver: defaultTrigger
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 6h
      routes:
      - match_re:
          service: service_overload
          owner: ATeam
        receiver: pagerDutyTrigger
    
    receivers:
    - name: 'pagerDutyTrigger'
      pagerduty_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        routing_key: <myPagerDutyToken>
```

Add some rule On /var/data/prometheus-stack/prometheus/**yourRuleFile.yml**

```yaml
    groups:
    - name: alerts
      rules:
      - alert: service_overload_more_than_5000
        expr: (node_network_receive_bytes_total{job="someJobOrService"} / 1000) >= 5000
        for: 10m
        labels:
          service: service_overload
          severity: pager
          dev_team: myteam
        annotations:
          dev_team: myteam
          priority: Blocker
          identifier: '{{ $labels.name }}'
          description: 'service overflow'
          value: '{{ humanize $value }}%'
```

On /var/data/prometheus-stack/prometheus/**prometheus.yml** add this snippet to integrate alertmanager:

```yaml
    global:
     
    ...
    
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - "alertmanager:9093"
    
    rule_files:
      - "yourRuleFile.yml"
    
    ...
```

Pay attention that the key point of this example is **service_overload** which connects and binds the rule into the right receiver.

**Reload the config** (restart the service again or stop and start your docker containers) and test it, if it's configured well you can watch the alerts in `http://your-prometheus-url:9090/alerts`