# How can I send multiple alerts to one receiver group in Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have looked at this question/answer here: [Prometheus AlertManager - Send Alerts to different clients based on routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485580/prometheus-alertmanager-send-alerts-to-different-clients-based-on-routes?answertab=active#tab-top)

And it was a pretty good start for me, and I wish I could've commented a quick question to the Answerer there but I don't have the rep.

Anyways, I have an **alert.rules.yml** file with two groups which looks like:

```
groups:
- name: DevOpsAlerts
  rules:

  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes. ({{ $value }} minutes)"

  - alert: InstanceHighCpu
    expr: 100 - (avg by (host) (irate(node_cpu{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) > 5
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.host }}: CPU High"
      description: "{{ $labels.host }} has high CPU activity"

- name: TestTeam2
  rules:

  - alert: - alert: InstanceLowMemory
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable < 268435456
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.host }}: memory low"
      description: "{{ $labels.host }} has less than 256M memory available"

  - alert: InstanceLowDisk
    expr: node_filesystem_avail{mountpoint="/"} < 1073741824
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.host }}: low disk space"
      description: "{{ $labels.host }} has less than 1G FS space"
```

Along with that I have an **alertmanager.yml** file which looks like

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'smtpserver'
  smtp_from: 'alertsender@email.com'
  smtp_auth_username: 'alertsender@email.com'
  smtp_auth_password: 'verystrongpassword'
  smtp_require_tls: maybe

route:
  group_by: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service']

  #default receiver
  receiver: DevOps
  routes:
    - match:
        alertname: InstanceDown
      receiver: DevOps

    - match:
        group: InstanceHighCpu
      receiver: test-team-1

inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: 'critical'
  target_match:
    severity: 'warning'
  equal: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service']

receivers:
- name: DevOps
  email_configs:
  # - to: devops_dude@email.com

- name: test-team-1
  email_configs:
  - to: test-dude1@email.com #This can be any email specified from the team

- name: team-name-2
  email_configs:
  - to: test_email@test.com #This can be any email specified from the team
```

So from what I've gathered I am able to route alerts to specific receiver groups by specifying an alert name from the alert rules file and routing that to a specific receiver.

The big question I really have is: Is there a way to route alerts to specific receivers based on **group names** as opposed to **alert names** from the alert rules file.

So instead of

```
routes:
  - match:
      alertname: InstanceDown
    receiver: DevOps
```

Is there some sort of way to implement:

```
routes:
  - match:
      group: DevOpsAlerts
    receiver: DevOps
```

I've been scouring the internet for some sort of example like this but I couldn't find anything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule group names are not exposed to the Alertmanager, they're there largely for debugging on the Prometheus side.

What you could do is add a `group: DevOpsAlerts` label to each of your alerts.

Comment: Ah, okay I'll give that a try.  I'm finding it hard to find concrete examples of this kind of stuff (i guess since it's open source docs).  Do you mean I could change my labels to:
labels:
  severity: critical
  group: DevOpsAlerts

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: With your help I've got it figure out, much appreciated brian. Cheers.

Comment: would be nice a detailed answer "for dummies" showing how the configuration would look after the fix